# Property 'withConverter' does not exist on type 'AngularFirestoreDocument<unknown>

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I'm building a web app using ionic angular and firestore. When I want to get specific fields of a document I know I have to map to an object and this is what I did.

```
export interface notificationModel{
    notificationId?: string;
    message?: string;
    contactId?: string;
}
export class userModel{
    userId?: string;
    name?: string;
    notifications?: notificationModel[];
    contacts?: string[];

    constructor (userId, name, notifications,contacts) {
        this.name = name;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.notifications = notifications;
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }

    getContacts(){
        return this.contacts;
    }
}
```

Here the userinfo collection stores users name, a contact list which is a string array and another collection called notifications of type notifications.

This is my converter

```
var userConverter = {
    toFirestore: function(userModel) {
      return {
        userId: userModel.userId,
        name: userModel.name,
        notifications: userModel.notifications,
        contacts: userModel.contacts,
        }
    },
    fromFirestore: function(snapshot, options){
      const data = snapshot.data(options);
      return new userModel(data.userId, data.name, data.notifications,data.contacts)
    }
```

I want to get the user and map it to my user model/class so that I can use the data freely but can seem to do so.
this is one of my methods to get the contacts of the user but getting this error

**Property 'withConverter' does not exist on type 'AngularFirestoreDocument**

```
 this.userInfosCollection.doc(userId)
    .withConverter(userConverter)
    .get().then(function(doc) {
      if (doc.exists){
        // Convert to City object
        var user = doc.data();
        // Use a City instance method
        console.log(user.getContacts());
      } else {
        console.log("No such document!")
      }}).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error)
      });

    }
```

other than solving this error I would like to know the best practices to storing and retrieving data like this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As stated in this issue [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2291), that it's open on AngularFire official repository, unfortunately, **`withConverter()` method is not supported within Angular's library.**

While I would recommend you to check the issue for more details, there is also this below code that should provide you with a possible workaround, that might help you, in case you really need to use a converter.

```
getCollectionWithConverter(): CollectionReference {
  return this.db.firestore.collection("<collection>").withConverter(this.converter)
}

createCourse(course: Course) {
  return this.db.collection(this.getCollectionWithConverter()).add(course);
}
```

In addition to that, you can get best practices and examples of how to get data and map it to object in the below articles.

- [How to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10)
- [Custom Objects](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/get-data#custom_objects)